# Почему в веб-приложении на странице выводится 8, а не 4?

Tags: c#

Код метода Configure класса Startup:

```csharp
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    int x = 2;
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        x = x * 2;  //  2 * 2 = 4
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Result: {x}");
    });
}
```

По идее, мы ожидаем 4, но получаем 8.
Почему? Это связано с асинхронностью? Или с тем, сколько запросов посылает браузер?

Comment: Причем тут асинхронность? У вас при каждом запросе значение удваивается. Может ваш браузер так себя ведет или еще чего.

Comment: И да, прежде чем продолжать задавать вопросы по любому непонятному пустяку - настоятельно рекомендую вам научиться пользоваться [отладкой приложений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger). Она в большинстве случаев снимает кучу вопросов "почему у меня здесь/тут/там не работает/работает неправильно/непонятно".

Comment: Ну да, Вы правы, это зависит от количества запросов. Вы создали замыкание на переменную x, она будет умножаться на 2 с каждым запросом.

Comment: ASP.NET? Добавьте нужный тег в таком случае.